# How do I make a monerod RPC call in Python? (e.g. /get_transactions)

Tags: monerod, rpc

I'm not very experienced with Python and I'm pretty sure this is just a syntax issue.

I'm trying to use the `monerod` daemon RPC `/get_transactions` method from [here](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_transactions).

I have no problem getting the examples [here](https://moneroexamples.github.io/python-json-rpc/) to work and this (non-json) RPC call works fine as well:

```
import requests
import json
def main():
    response = requests.post("http://localhost:18081/getheight")
    r=response.json()
    print(r)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

However, whenever I try to use `/get_transactions` like this:

```
    transactionList = ["d6e48158472848e6687173a91ae6eebfa3e1d778e65252ee99d7515d63090408"]
    PARAMS = {'txs_hashes' : transactionList ,
              'decode_as_json' : True}
    myTransactions = requests.post("http://localhost:18081/get_transactions", params = PARAMS)
    print(myTransactions)
```

It always returns an error such as:

```
<Response [404]>
```

I'm pretty sure I'm just passing it the parameters incorrectly but I've tried a bunch of different permutations and checked the requests documentation and still can't get it to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are so very close.

Just change `params = PARAMS` to `json = PARAMS` and it will work.

From the requests [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests):

> Using the json parameter in the request will change the Content-Type in the header to application/json.

And to get the response text, use:

```
print(myTransactions.text)
```

Or to get the response as a json object:

```
print(myTransactions.json())
```